# PowerShell, Windows Terminal size and position manipulation

Tags: powershell, console, window, windows-terminal

I use some functions (below) in my `$Profile` to move and resize my PowerShell **consoles**. These work very nicely. I would like to use `Windows Terminal` more but I would also like to have these types of operations work there and presumably there must be some techniques to manipulate these windows (either PowerShell or accessing `.NET` functions).

**How can I achieve similar results to the below within Windows Terminal sessions?**

Note that this question is *specifically* about manipulation of the new `Windows Terminal` and **not** the PowerShell `console` (where the below work fine). The new Windows Terminal from Microsoft is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0)

Here's my code:

```
function Global:Set-ConsolePosition ($x, $y, $w, $h) {
    # Note: the DLL code below should not be indented from the left-side
    Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int W, int H); '
    # Do the Add-Type outside of the function as repeating it in a session can cause errors
    $consoleHWND = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow();
    $consoleHWND = [Console.Window]::MoveWindow($consoleHWND, $x, $y, $w, $h);
    # $consoleHWND = [Console.Window]::MoveWindow($consoleHWND,75,0,600,600);
    # $consoleHWND = [Console.Window]::MoveWindow($consoleHWND,-6,0,600,600);
}
function lll {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
    $width = $Screen.WorkingArea.Width   # .WorkingArea ignores the taskbar, .Bounds is whole screen
    $height = $Screen.WorkingArea.Height
    $w = $width/2 + 13
    $h = $height + 8
    $x = -7
    $y = 0
    Set-ConsolePosition $x $y $w $h

    $MyBuffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize
    $MyWindow = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize
    $MyBuffer.Height = 9999
    "`nWindowSize $($MyWindow.Width)x$($MyWindow.Height) (Buffer $($MyBuffer.Width)x$($MyBuffer.Height))"
    "Position : Left:$x Top:$y Width:$w Height:$h`n"
}
function rrr {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
    $width = $Screen.WorkingArea.Width   # .WorkingArea ignores the taskbar, .Bounds is whole screen
    $height = $Screen.WorkingArea.Height
    $w = $width/2 + 13
    $h = $height + 8
    $x = $w - 20
    $y = 0
    Set-ConsolePosition $x $y $w $h

    $MyBuffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize
    $MyWindow = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize
    $MyBuffer.Height = 9999
    "`nWindowSize $($MyWindow.Width)x$($MyWindow.Height) (Buffer $($MyBuffer.Width)x$($MyBuffer.Height))"
    "Position : Left:$x Top:$y Width:$w Height:$h`n"
}
function fff {
    Set-ConsolePosition -7 0 600 600
    if ($Host.Name -match "console") {
        $MaxHeight = $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize.Height - 1
        $MaxWidth = $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize.Width
        $MyBuffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize
        $MyWindow = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize
        $MyWindow.Height = $MaxHeight
        $MyWindow.Width = $Maxwidth
        $MyBuffer.Height = 9999
        $MyBuffer.Width = $Maxwidth
        # $host.UI.RawUI.set_bufferSize($MyBuffer)
        # $host.UI.RawUI.set_windowSize($MyWindow)
        $host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $MyBuffer
        $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = $MyWindow
        "`nWindowSize $($MyWindow.Width)x$($MyWindow.Height) (Buffer $($MyBuffer.Width)x$($MyBuffer.Height))`n"
    }
}
```